# How to sort id records of data in a table of SQL Server from high to low

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting

I have a problem to sort data by ID, I tried `order by ASC` and `DESC` but none of them did what I need.

Normally records registered into table from low to high, for example:

```
ID   column1     column2 
-------------------------
1    test1        test1
2    test2        test2
3    test3        test3
```

but I would like to records data to tables from high to low as follow

```
ID   column1     column2 
-------------------------
3    test1        test1
2    test2        test2
1    test3        test3
```

your help would be appreciated.

As I said I would like to see the records in table of database from high to low.

Comment: If records register into table from high to low, what happens when `ID` reaches 0? BTW, insertion and querying are not the same thing. _Sort_ in SQL is more like a _SELECT_ operation and you're trying to apply it in _INSERT_.

Comment: The ID order/values are unimportant. Don't try to "re-order" them.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want the ID's in reversed order but the rest of the columns in the normal order:

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID DESC) AS ID,
    column1,
    column2
FROM dbo.Table1 
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

<kbd>[**`DEMO`**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8d396/3/0)</kbd>

If you actually want the latest 7 records but those must be in reverse order:

```
SELECT x.* FROM (
   SELECT TOP 7 t.*
   FROM dbo.Table1 t
   ORDER BY t.ID DESC
) x
ORDER BY x.ID DESC
```

<kbd>[**`DEMO`**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8d396/6/0)</kbd>

Comment: in fact , I have many record in my table but I would like just select 7 latest record and show them into a chart, when in try by "order by" the sort is not correct because it shows the days Reverse, for example 17,16,15 ,14 , but I would like to show 14, 15,16 ,17 , just 7 latest records

Comment: SELECT TOP 7 SUBSTRING(DATENAME(MONTH,[Time]),0,4)+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEPART(DAY,[Time])) Day FROM [PL-PK] ORDER BY Id ASC"

Comment: @Mom: i don't understand why you don't use `SELECT TOP 7 ... ORDER BY Id DESC`

Comment: I tried it , but it shows only 7 top records of my database which is started by ID >> 1,2,3,4 .... not latest inserted , I want to select 7 latest inserted records. for example id of latest records are between 40 and 47 , I don't know how can I select them

Comment: If you use `ORDER BY Id DESC` you will get the seven latest records, if you use `ORDER BY Id ASC` you will get the first seven records.

Comment: yes , but in my chart the dates started from up to down but I want start from down to up, I uploaded some screen shot , as you see the date started from 20,Sep to 14,Sep (left to right) but I want start from 14 to 20 (left to right )
http://postimg.org/image/bjlpn34dr/
http://postimg.org/image/p10ejdxvf/

Comment: So you want the seven latest records but those should be ordered descending?

Comment: @Mom: you need a subquery like the one i've shown now

Comment: it is exactly what I want but how can I adapt it into my query ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, relational database doesn't consider order of select statement.
That means select doesn't affect on order rows of table.
Because it stores in its own structure that makes faster to retrieve data
depends on index or etc..